# for each module, inject a different provider into a controller without providers interfering

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have the following nestjs classes and modules. Each module uses the same controller, but a different provider is injected into the controller for each module. I may not be using the nestjs' dependency injection framework properly, but what happens is that the last injected service (ServiceC) appears in each of the modules. Is there a way to stop this interference from happening? I've tried injecting using `useFactory` but to no avail. I would like each module to inject a unique service that extends `MyAbstractService` as described below.

```
    export class MyController {
      constructor(
        @Inject("COMMON_SERVICE") private readonly commonService: MyAbstractService,
      ) {
      commonService.doSomething();
      }
    }
```

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ServiceA extends MyAbstractService {
      public doSomething(){
      }
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class ServiceB extends MyAbstractService {
      public doSomething(){
      }
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class ServiceC extends MyAbstractService {
      public doSomething(){
      }
    }
```

```
    @Module({
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: "COMMON_SERVICE",
          useClass: ServiceA,
        },
    ]})
    export class ModuleA

    @Module({
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: "COMMON_SERVICE"
          useClass: ServiceB,
        },]
    })
    export class ModuleB

    @Module({
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: "COMMON_SERVICE"
          useClass: ServiceC,
        },]
    })
    export class ModuleC
```

And finally a main module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ModuleA,
    ModuleB,
    ModuleC
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

```
function main(){
  const app = await NestFactory.create(MainModule);
}
```

EDIT
I've now realised that in normal operation (when `NestFactory.create(MainModule)` is used), dependency injection works as expected without any issues. However, in my `jest` test harness, I use

```
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [MainModule],
    }).compile();
    const controller = module
      .select(ModuleB)
      .get<MyController>(MyController);
```

to build the main module and extract its controller. In this scenario I can test the `MyController` that resides in `ModuleB`. I would expect the controller to be injected with `ServiceB`. However, as already stated, `ServiceC` is injected instead.

Comment: might have to do with that `commonProviders` that you didn't show. What if you drop that?

Comment: @MicaelLevi - sorry, a typo, wasn't mean to include them in the example. I've removed them now.

Comment: ok. Are you saying that the `commonService` prop is always an instance of `ServiceC`?

Comment: @MicaelLevi - in reality, yes I do have some other common providers in each module, but I thought these to be irrelevant in illustrating the basic structure. Could they be part of the issue I am seeing?

Comment: probably because the code you shared is fine. There is no way of `commonService` be an instance of `ServiceC` on both `ModuleB` and `ModuleA`. And I just tested this myself.

Comment: @MicaelLevi - please see my recent edit. I've realised that indeed, everything works during normal operation as expected. However, during testing when a test module is created, dependency injection does not work as expected.

Comment: now I'd suggest you to open a new issue at https://github.com/nestjs/nest to report that behavior as a bug